# mootools className undefined

Tags: javascript, mootools, classname

I really don't understand why that piece of code won't work :

```
$$('.nav_contact').addEvent('click', function(){  
    if (this.getStyle('color') != '#ffc000') {
        this.tween('color','#ffc000');
        alert(this.className);
        $$('.navigation').getElements('a').each(function(a) {
            alert(a.className);
            if (a.className != 'nav_contact') {
                a.tween('color','#b2b1af');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

here is the related HTML :

```
<nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="nav_foo">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav_bar">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav_contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
```

This is supposed to highlight the clicked button and to somehow hide the other ones. The problem is that I can't get elements className soon as I enter the each. The alert gives me "undefined".
Anybody ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be hard to scale / pattern as is.

consider something like this:

```
(function() {
    var navItems = $$(".navigation a");

    document.getElements("a.nav_contact").addEvent("click", function() {
        var self = this;
        if (this.getStyle('color') != '#ffc000') {
            this.tween('color', '#ffc000');

            navItems.each(function(a) {
                // more scalable - change all but the current one w/o special references.
                if (a != self) {                      
                    a.tween('color', '#b2b1af');
                }

                return;
                // or check if it has an implicit class name...
                if (!a.hasClass("nav_contact"))
                    a.tween('color', '#b2b1af');

                // or check if the only class name is matching...
                if (a.get("class") != 'nav_contact')
                    a.tween('color', '#b2b1af');


            });
        }
    });
})();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/V26Fk/

To answer your original question though. Even though CURRENTLY mootools returns a proper element object, it will not always be the case. Do not assume it will be and ALWAYS use the api to get properties of the object, eg. `element.get("class")` vs `el.className` - it does the browser differences mapping as well. same for value, text etc - just discipline your self to use the API or you wont be able to upgrade to mootools 2.0

Comment: thx for your answer Dimitar. It works so I'll also update the rest of my code.

Comment: oh and I wanted to ask you why you changed the original '$$('.nav_contact')' by 'document.getElements("a.nav_contact")'

Comment: I don't like $$ :) in the old days it was an alias for `this.document.getElements()` - which could misbehave on a different context of execution. code should be more verbal and self explanatory so if somebody comes in and looks at it w/o mootools experience, they don't need to know what $$ does and can understand the code as is.